# use ajax get value outside ajaxstatement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript inside which I use ajax to get a value.
But when I want to use that value outside of the ajax statement it does not work.

My code:

```
var value;
$.get("ajaxstatus.php",
  {id: id})
.done(function(data) {
  value = data
  alert('inner' + data)
});
alert('outer' + value)
```

The alert with the inner just gives me the value I get back from the ajax,  but when I want to use the value in the outer alert it is empty because it isn't assigned yet.
I have the exact same problem when I use ajax `post` instead of `get`.

How do I get the value I get back from the ajax statement also outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous, meaning that where possible, it doesn't block processing while evaluating code. So, while your ajax call may take some time to return, javascript keeps processing your code all the way to the end. When your AJAX call finally returns, it triggers a callback, which is `.done()`.

So...

```
$.get("ajaxstatus.php",
  {id: id})
.done(function(data){
  doWork(data);
});

function doWork(data) {
  alert('after' + data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this a classic asynchrone problem, you have to use "data" inside the done callback.

read thing about [promise](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-promises),  [async / await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=568g8hxJJp4&vl=fr) can help you i think